# NPRuntime plugin says Missing Plug-in in Safari(Windows)

Tags: safari, npapi, browser-plugin, npruntime

I have developed an NPRuntime plugin, everything is ok, but it not initialized in Safari. I registered the plugin in MozillaPlugins registry key, it works fine for Chrome/FF/Opera, but Safari writes the the plugin is missing, although I found my plugin in the list of isntalled safari plugins. What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

That's real hard to say.  Safari on windows isn't supported real well by Apple, so I don't bother supporting it much myself.  If it's really important I'd recommend adding logging in all your NPP_ methods (and your NP_ functions too) and see what is getting called; find out if it even loads your plugin.  Often if something doesn't go as the browser wants during startup it will act like it didn't find it at all.

You could also use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see if it is trying to load the file or not.